# Draw only 2 ellipses in PCA plot (instead of 20)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggfortify

I have a PCA plot created with ggplot/ggfortify
and the function `autoplot()`, such as in this question: [Change point colors and color of frame/ellipse around points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640492/change-point-colors-and-color-of-frame-ellipse-around-points)

```
head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]
autoplot(prcomp(df))
autoplot(prcomp(df), data = iris, colour = 'Species')
autoplot(prcomp(df), data = iris, colour = 'Species', shape='Species', frame=T)
```

Is there a way to draw only 1 or 2 frames/ellipses, instead of all of them, in the PCA plot?

Comment: maybe manually change fill/colour to NA for the ellipses/frames you don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `autoplot` is that, although it is great for producing nice visualizations of common data structures and models with little effort, it doesn't give you the full freedom to customize the plot. However, it is pretty straightforward to do the whole thing within ggplot. The following is a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

pc <- prcomp(iris[1:4])
df <- cbind(pc$x[,1:2], iris)

ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.3))),
               data = df[df$Species != "versicolor",])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>